# How to close a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Here is part of my code:

```
import tkinter

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(1000, 500, bg="yellow")
        self.canvas.pack()
```

Which command should I use in order to close tkinter window (canvas)?

Comment: But is the canvas even shown with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
self.canvas.destroy()
```

Or if you actually want to close the whole window and not just remove the `Canvas`:

```
self.root.destroy()
```

Comment: And what should I add to self.root then?

Comment: @bartolomo What you mean by that?

Comment: In def __init__(self): 
  self.root = ?

Comment: your init should be `def __init__(self, root): ...` And then to run it you use: `root = tk.Tk(); program = Program(root); root.mainloop()`

Comment: @bartolomo See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17466968/9835872 for a clean object oriented tkinter demo.

Comment: When I do that this appears: 'Program' object has no attribute 'root'. Shouldn´t I really add something to self.root?

Comment: You should have at least: `self.root = root` in your `__init__`

Comment: I really advice you to go read or watch some tkinter tutorials before posting more questions this basic.